# Shiny app - an elegant way to display images only if the files exist

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am currently working on a Shiny application (deployed with shiny-server, open source edition) that takes various input values and then launches a task (heavy computations) when the user clicks an `actionButton`. This task is performed by calling a script from the command line. It has to be run in the background (using `system("whatever", wait = FALSE)`) because if R waits for the command to be completed, no other user can access the application.

The results of this script are images that I want to be displayed on the UI. At the moment, I'm checking periodically if the files exist by using `invalidateLater` in an 'observe()' context (server.R). If the files are found, then a boolean value is set to TRUE instead of FALSE and the output are displayed.

It is working fine but it seems a bit hackish to me. I wanted to know if there is **a more elegant/convenient way to display an image only if the file exist** than checking periodically if the file is there or not ?  I can't think of any at the moment.

Comment: any chance to make use of `reactiveFileReader`?

Comment: It looks like a good solution though I don't think it will work if the files don't exist at first (while the 'heavy' script is running). I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Well, in this case you can create file ahead of time.

Comment: (I'm just leaving this comment if anyone else wonders how to proceed). 
If you are in a case where you can create the files ahead of time, then the approach described by @Marat Talipov (using `reactiveFileReader`) seems to be the best. 
In any other case, I don't think that there is a better way than checking if the files exist or not periodically (by the way, even `reactiveFileReader`is executed every X milliseconds to check changes of a given file).